# Export and Import Posts and Comments list for new site issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, blog

I export and import the Posts list and also comments list in SharePoint 2013 to another site,imported successfully. When I am clicking on each post I am unable to see the comments.

How can I get the comments to that particular blog post?